# Wicket - get the selected item in the DropDownChoice using Scala

Tags: scala, wicket

How can I get the selected item form a DropDownChoice inside an ListView?

I implemented the chunky code bellow:

```
val listCustomer: java.util.List[Customer] = customerDAO.listCustomers

item.add(new DropDownChoice("customerSelection", listCustomer, new ChoiceRenderer[Customer]("name")))
```

In this case I want to get the name property displayed of the model Customer.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
new DropDownChoice[Customer](("customerSelection", new Model[Customer], listCustomer, new ChoiceRenderer[Customer]("name"))) {
  protected override def wantOnSelectionChangedNotifications: Boolean = true

  protected override def onSelectionChanged(newSelection: Customer) {
    super.onSelectionChanged(newSelection)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much @Alexey, I changed the code for this new DropDownChoice[Customer](("customerSelection", new PropertyModel(Customer, "name") ...etc and I'm getting the error java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.sys.entities.Customer Could you please tell me what I'm doing wrong?